# span and width issue

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm using a `fullcalendar` library as you can see.  The problem is when the words get long it hides the first word and shows the next word on a new line.

I want it to be like...

```
verylongverylong
verylong
appointment
```

Something like this.  So i tried to change this cell's width like this.

```
.fc-event-title{
    display: block;
}
```

[image]

After this, the width has been shorter but still it cuts the word.

Any good idea?

Comment: Did you try `word-wrap:break-word`? [See](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)

Comment: I can't recreate your issue with the information you've provided. Screen shots are not a substitute for the actual HTML.

Comment: The images here are practically pointless.  Copy and paste your code instead and make the images a bit larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add css style to your span:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: Thank you for the SUPER FAST response! :) I'll choose this after 5min. It takes time after uploading a new thread to choose answer